# How to animate My Calling Activity

Tags: android, animation

I developing one android app in which there are  two Activities . I want to open second activity with animation when I click on a button.anybody please help, I don't know completely.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No downvote. You should always [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Activity+transition+in+Android) before posting new questions.

Comment: If you have no idea where to start, I suggest you start by reading up developer information and tutorials on android documentation site.  Then try putting the code together.  If the codes doesn't work as expected, post it here - and we'll try to help.  However please don't expect us to do the work for you.

Answer (score 1):

its pretty simple to do it.please Google it you will get it.... use [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)
to call next activity and use [Animation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html)
for effect.and if you are satisfied with ans. then accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Use overridePendingTransistion()

```
startActivity(intent);
//animation_in/out are animation declared in xml
overridePendingTransition(animation_in,animation_out);
```

Comment: thanks for ur responce but it is not working.i m using startActivityforResult.